# How to use walker to replace core function

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I want to modify the way pages are listed in the navigation, particularly the function el_start from wp-includes/classes.php.

I've first modified the classes.php directly and it worked fine butnow I want to revert classes.php and move the modification out of wordpress' internal files.

I wrote a walker class that I want to use but I don't know how to use it.  I want to replace the current call wp_list_pages() to this:

```
 $walker_pages = new Walker_Page_CustomTitle;
 wp_list_pages(array('walker' => $walker_pages, 'title_li' => '', 'depth' => '1'));
```

I've tried using a filter like so:

```
function wp_list_pages_custom() {
     $walker_pages = new Walker_Page_CustomTitle;
     wp_list_pages(array('walker' => $walker_pages, 'title_li' => '', 'depth' => '1'));
}
add_filter('widget_area_primary_aside', 'wp_list_pages_custom');
```

But with this filter, the site won't load anymore.

The tutorial [here](http://bugssite.org/blog/2009/12/08/wordpress-custom-walker-tutorial/) says I should put this code in header.php but that just puts my page links in the  tag.

I hope I'm making sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be ideal if `wp_list_pages()` had a filter on the passed arguments, before it executed any further code.

However, the best approach I can see, whereby simply using `wp_list_pages()` without passing a walker argument uses *your* walker is like so;

```
function my_custom_wp_pages($list, $args)
{
    $walker = new Walker_Page_CustomTitle;
    $args = array_merge($args, array('walker' => $walker, 'echo' => false);

    remove_filter('wp_list_pages', 'my_custom_wp_pages'); // avoid endless loop

    $list = wp_list_pages($args);

    add_filter('wp_list_pages', 'my_custom_wp_pages'); // add it back

    return $list;
}
add_filter('wp_list_pages', 'my_custom_wp_pages', 5, 2);
```

UPDATE:

Edited the `add_filter` call to accept two arguments.

Comment: With a little bit of editing (for example $args is not an array here so I had to put a is_array condition before array_merge) this worked beautifully.

I understood the code, thank you very much.

Comment: Glad to help :) The filter `wp_list_pages` will always pass back `$args` as an array, so this shouldn't be a problem (check my revised answer).